# Sequence and Series

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Use any programming language to display numbers divisible by 1000000 that are greater than 1 and less than 10000000. Each number should be displayed in new line. Your program should display exactly:

```
1000000
2000000
3000000
4000000
5000000
6000000
7000000
8000000
9000000
```

Comment: Hi, I closed your question as a duplicate of an older question, because the challenge specified there is pretty much the intent of this question. The other question is about testing divisibility between two numbers.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Not all answers here can be ported there, this one is more trivial. (being trivial should not be a reason for closing)

Answer (score 3):

## Japt `-R`, 5 bytes

```
9õ*L³
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=OfUqTLM=&input=LVI=)

---

### Explanation

```
9õ        :Range [1,9]
  *       :Multiply each by
   L      :100
    ³     :Cubed
          :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
i=0;exec'i+=10**6;print i;'*9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWwDq1IjVZPVPb1tBAS8vMuqAoM69EIdNaXcvy/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 13 bytes

```bash
seq {1,1,9}e6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UKHaUMdQx7I21ez/fwA)

This answer is found out by [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

Comment: `seq {1,1,9}e6`

Comment: @manatwork great! never heard such a notation before.

Comment: Is just a usual [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion). `echo seq {1,1,9}e6` will show you that it expands to your original code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 85 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_EXIT][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   T   T   T   T   S T S S S N
_Push_1000][S N
S _Duplicate][T S S N
_Multiply][T    S S N
_Multiply][T    N
S T _Print_number][S S S T  S T S N
_Push_10][T N
S S _Print_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LYxdCgAgCIOf3Sl2tQih3oKCjm/@pAy3D@Yd8@herasZScDlVyBkWYpvxGT4LIbCAsFTaX8hPwFmDw) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Pseudo-code:**

```
Integer i = 0
Start LOOP:
  i = i + 1
  If(i == 10):
    Exit with an error
  Integer j = 1000 * 1000 * i
  Print j as number to STDOUT
  Print "\n"
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 14 bytes

```powershell
1..9|%{$_*1e6}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz7JGtVolXssw1az2/38A)

Simply loops from `1` to `9` and multiplies each by `1e6`, i.e., `1000000`, to give the appropriate numbers. Ho-hum boring. Saved 7 bytes thanks to mazzy.

Previous versions:

---

#### [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 21 bytes

```powershell
1..9|%{"$_"+"000000"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz7JGtVpJJV5JW8kADJRq//8HAA)

Boring simple loop from `1` to `9` that just string-concatenates the output together.

---

#### [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 21 bytes

```powershell
1e6..9e6|?{!($_%1e6)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3zDVTE/PMtWsxr5aUUMlXhXI16z9/x8A)

Loops from `1e6` to `9e6`, pulls out those entries where they're divisible by `1e6`. Times out on TIO but works offline. [Run it with 3 instead of 6](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3zDVWE/PMtW4xr5aUUMlXhXI16z9/x8A) to see the logic better.

Comment: ? `1..9|%{$_*1e6}`

Comment: @mazzy Of course! The most boring solution yet! Haha.

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 8 bytes

```
9Δμ7)_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/3/LclHN7zD/MndoHxN2a8f///8svKMnMzyv@r5sHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 11, <s>62</s> <s>61</s> <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=0;i++<9;)System.out.println(i*1000000);}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@ggorlen*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY4xDoMwDEV3TuExKQLRsUrpDWBB6lJ1cANUpiEgEiJViLOngeLB1rf1n3@HDpOu/nip0BgokPQSAZC2zdSibKDcJIAbqAbJ7ttwXITdGoVmLFqSUIKGHLxLbks7TCy4gfJMUBxfL4JXX2ObPh1mm45TuCnN6HTO9uJi9WIjjfNLBdIB3N/1IQyrbLC8H09A/k@iU8n0rNQRYvU/)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                        // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  v->{for(int i=0;i++<9;)   //  Loop `i` in the range (0,9]
    System.out.println(     //   Print without trailing newline:
     i*1000000);}           //    `i` multiplied by 1,000,000
```

Comment: You could save a couple bytes with `v->{for(int i=0;i++<9;)System.out.println(i*1000000);}`

Comment: @ggorlen Can't believe I didn't check if that was shorter.. I did try `printf("%.0f%n",i*1e6)` and `println((int)(i*1e6))` but forgot about just `println(i*1000000)`.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
9L6°*»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0sfs0AatQ7v//wcA)

**Explanation:**

```python
9L        # List in the range [1,9]
  6°*     # Multiply each by 10**6
     »    # Join the list by newlines (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

```python
for i in range(1,10):print(i*10**6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1DH0EDTqqAoM69EI1PL0EBLy0zz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 17 bytes

```
Ϩ²:(
;|:.
,':"+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N/////IpDm6w0uKxrrPS4dNStlLT//wcA)

### Explanation

```
Ϩ    # Push 1k
 ²   # Square the value
  :( # Copy the value for the accumulator
;|   # Repeat 10-1 times:
  :. # Print TOS
,    # Print newline
 ':" # Copy 1m to TOS
    + #Add the values
```

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 8 bytes (SBCS) (Doesn't seem to work online yet)

```
9Ï_⑷ė6Ë*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f8nB//KOJ249MNzvcrfX//3/dgrz/unn5AA)

### Explanation

```
9Ï_     #Generate range 1-9 by generating range 0-9 and discarding 0
   ⑷        #Map the following to each element:
    ė6Ë*    #   Multiply each by 10 to the power of 6
#-pn puts newlines between each item, which is printed using -no
```

Comment: [8 bytes using `-pn` and `-no` combined with `Ï`](https://tio.run/##y05N///f8nB//KOJ249MNzvcrfX//3/dgrz/unn5AA "Keg – Try It Online"). N.B. TIO needs updating of Keg

Comment: [8 byter explained](https://tio.run/##LU67bcMwFKylKQ5QF0SA3BiwF0jlGQLaOkuE6UeCpEB4BheGq4ySAZxJsghDQunu3fddOOW8ez0@f5/fP1/b1/2trVfTdB8UehUJr2QiNv0OxxumldUy/fND4ZWMGHU4KT9WYWgBlL5SclAOcSbO1hibqhgtqE4zaHilxH31Yl1uuuawmKidua2esrcZaqJWOJvoYc/Ytl3vBG6JAcJktDDgyJhIWXM68vqONOuKA5zXEjliCfWBXmzOuTTkgv4A "Keg – Try It Online")

Comment: Yeah. It's been around for a few weeks now so it's relatively new.

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `n` `d`, 5 bytes

```
-í╞6\
```

### Explanation

Decompressed:

```
9    M % Map in the range 1..9
 a  *  % Multiply the current item by ...
  6^   % ... 10 to the power of 6
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 35 bytes

```javascript
for(i=0;i++<9;)console.log(i*10**6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9II9PWwDpTW9vG0lozOT@vOD8nVS8nP10jU8vQQEvLTPP/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 16 bytes

```
Output[1:9*10^6]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/37@0pKC0JNrQylLL0CDOLPb/fwA)

### Explanation

```
Output[1:9*10^6]
       1:9          the range from 1 to 9
          *10^6     multiplied by 10^6 (1e6)
Output[        ]    output each entry on its own line
```

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 29 bytes

```
/!/000000
/1!2!3!4!5!6!7!8!9!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19R3wAMuPQNFY0UjRVNFE0VzRTNFS0ULRX//wcA)

33 bytes for no trailing newline:

```
/"/000//!/""
/1!2!3!4!5!6!7!8!9""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19J38DAQF9fUV9JiUvfUNFI0VjRRNFU0UzRXNFC0VJJ6f9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## C++ 44 bytes

```
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){cout<<i*100**6<<endl;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>48</strike> 44 bytes

```cs
for(int i=0;i++<9;)Console.WriteLine(i*1e6);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsIwEAbgV7kxsSi6CCU6SFedHJxDesoP9Q5y14KUPnv8vmL7opXbbJAPPX/m/E1UpmxGN1rJPDsKLYqRHhkSIq3trTVAnHA9JnTdpU9xUDGd@PCqcL5DOGB34nNMbdvaHw)

*-4 bytes: changed* `i*1000000` *to* `i*1e6` *in* `Console.WriteLine()`

Ungolfed:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i++ < 9;)               // from 1 to 9
    Console.WriteLine(i * 1e6);     // write i times 1,000,000 (1e6 = 1*(10^6) = 1,000,000) to the console
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 16 bytes

```
9*
L$`.
$.>`6*0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8tSi8tHJUGPS0XPLsFMy@D/fwA) Explanation:

```
9*
```

Insert 9 `_`s.

```
L$`.
```

List a value for each `_`.

```
$.>`6*0
```

Number of characters up to and including the current `_` followed by six zeros.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program.

```apl
⍪1E6×⍳9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@j3lWGrmaHpz/q3WwJEvmvAAYFAA)

`⍳9` **ɩ**ndices one through nine

`1E9×` multiply million by those

`⍪` columnify

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), <strike>30</strike> 24 bytes

```
(1..9).map{|d|p d*10**6}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8NQT89SUy83saC6JqWmQCFFy9BAS8us9v9/AA)

-6 bytes: use `map` instead of `step`. Use `10**6` instead of `1e6.to_i`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>31</del> 26 bytes

```
00000000: ba10 018b fab1 09b4 09cd 21fe 05e2 fac3  ..........!.....
00000010: 3130 3030 3030 300d 0a24                 1000000..$
```

Listing:

```
BA 0110     MOV  DX, OFFSET O           ; DOS pointer to output string 
8B FA       MOV  DI, DX                 ; pointer to defrerence for increment 
B1 09       MOV  CL, 9                  ; counter to 9 
8A E1       MOV  AH, CL                 ; DOS write string function also to 9 
        LOOPY: 
CD 21       INT  21H                    ; write string to stdout 
FE 05       INC  BYTE PTR[DI]           ; increment first digit 
E2 FA       LOOP LOOPY                  ; loop 9 times 
C3          RET                         ; return to DOS 
        O:  DB  '1000000',0DH,0AH,'$'   ; output string
```

Standalone DOS executable, output to STDOUT.

[image]

*TODO: re-do screenshot with old program length!*

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
9Rȷ6×Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98y6MR2s8PTI///BwA)

## Explanation

```
9R     [1, 2, ..., 8, 9]
  ȷ6   100000
    ×  Multiply each
     Y Join by newline
```